# EF Code First(existing database) Relate single entity with two table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How map single entity with multiple table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070664/how-map-single-entity-with-multiple-table)

I want to get data from two tables and store it into one entity. How??

Entity Class:

```
 public class HomeViewModel
{
    [Key]
    [Column("candidate_ID")]
    public int candidateID { get; set; }
    [Column("first_name")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    [Column("last_name")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

   // [Column("")]
    public string emailID { get; set; }
   // [Column("")]
    public string mb_country_code { get; set; }
    //[Column("")]
    public int mobile_no { get; set; }
}
```

Above entity class holds 6 property where 3 property represents ont table1 and 3 represents table2.

 At database table 1 holds candidate_id as primary key and tablte two holds candidate_id as foreign key.